# Why is dissociate not working immediately on my Laravel model?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is some of my code:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }

    public function emptyCart() {
        $orders = $this->orders;

        foreach($orders as $order) {
            $order->user()->dissociate();
            $order->save();
        }       

        if ($this->orders) {
            echo 'Orders still exist?'
        } 
    }
}
```

My echo statement is being hit. If I refresh my app, there are no orders attached, but immediately after I "empty" my cart, it is returning orders as if I hadn't removed them...

Interestingly, the "order" models that get returned have `user_id` set as null.

Comment: I don't know laravel at all, but guessing from the syntax shouldn't it be `$this->$order->dissociate()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$this->orders` is a relationship attribute. Once the relationship is loaded (via eager loading or lazy loading), the relationship will not be reloaded unless explicitly done in the code.

So, in the beginning of your function, you access the `$this->orders` attribute. If the orders have not been loaded yet, they will be lazy loaded at this point. You then go through and dissociate the orders from the user. This correctly sets the `user_id` to null, and updates the database (with your `save()`), but it will not remove the items from the Collection that is already loaded.

If you would like the `$this->orders` attribute to reflect the current state of the relationships after you're done modifying the relationships, you will need to explicitly reload the relationship. Example below:

```
public function emptyCart() {
    // gets the Collection of orders
    $orders = $this->orders;

    // modifies orders in the Collection, and updates the database
    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $order->user()->dissociate();
        $order->save();
    }

    // reload the relationship
    $this->load('orders');       

    // now there will be no orders
    if ($this->orders) {
        echo 'Orders still exist?'
    } 
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I couldn't find this in the docs, or maybe I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: @Rail24 I don't think it is specifically mentioned in the docs. I couldn't find it after a quick search. One of those things you learn along the way. Diving into the source code can really help figure out how these things work, as well. Not feasible when you're just trying to get something done, but maybe when you have some down time and get interested.